# using auto fill to sequentially add onto an equation by rows of 4

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I am having some trouble using excel. I have this equation I am trying to have autofilled.

`=(SUMPRODUCT(Mortality!$C21:$C24,'Relative risks'!$B$6:$B$9)-    SUMPRODUCT(Mortality!$C2888:$C$2891,'Relative risks'!$B$6:$B$9))/(SUMPRODUCT(Mortality!$C$21:$C$24,'Relative risks'!$B$6:$B$9))`

My goal is to have autofill change c21:c24 to c25:c28 sequentially.

Thanks for any help.

Ariel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to peel out the range using a pair of `INDEX` functions defining the start and end then join them with a colon.

[image: OFFSET with SUMPRODUCT]

I have only used a portion of your full formula but I believe ti adequately demonstrates the method. The formula in E7 is,

`=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX(Mortality!$C:$C, 21+(ROW(1:1)-1)*4):INDEX(Mortality!$C:$C, 24+(ROW(1:1)-1)*4)), 'Relative risks'!$B$6:$B$9)`

Fill down as necessary. The formulas in D7:D10 were your original function with the ranges changes manually in order to provide a check and balance for the results.

Comment: Hello, this worked. Thanks so much. You are awesome. I've been working on this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of OFFSET() and ROW() to increment an input range by a fixed amount per row filled down.

Simple example (C1 has the formula shown):

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I had tried the following but is showing an error of #VALUE!. The reference cells are all numbers. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks again. =(SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(Mortality!$C$21:$C$24,(COLUMN()-6)*4,0,4,1),'Relative risks'!$B$6:$B$9)- SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(Mortality!$C$33:$C$36,(COLUMN()-6)*4,0,4,1),'Relative risks'!$B$6:$B$9))/(SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(Mortality!$C$21:$C$24,(COLUMN()-6)*4,0,4,1),'Relative risks'!$B$6:$B$9))

Comment: If you break it down to the sub-formulas does each one work by itself ?

Comment: No each sub-formula does not work. For the original formula the sub-formulas work. This is the original formula: =(SUMPRODUCT(Mortality!$C$21:$C$24,'Relative risks'!$D$6:$D$9)-SUMPRODUCT(Mortality!$C$33:$C$36,'Relative risks'!$D$6:$D$9))/(SUMPRODUCT(Mortality!$C$21:$C$24,'Relative risks'!$D$6:$D$9))    I think the formula I created with OFFSET AND COLUMN is not set up correctly but I'm not sure why. Thanks again for all your great help.

Comment: Yep - Seems like you cannot use ROW() inside of SUMPRODUCT() - sorry to have led you down this path ;-(    I can oly suggest referencing some other "helper" row containing the values you would have gotten from COLUMN() here.

Comment: Oh well, too bad. Thanks for the info. I'm unsure how to set up a helper row. Thanks again.

Comment: Try `=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(Mortality!$C$21:$C$24,INDEX((COLUMN(A:A)-1)*4;1),0,4,1),'Relative risks'!$B$6:$B$9)`

Comment: I tried it and the message "the formula you typed contains an error" appeared. It then highlights the 4 after the * in the formula. Thanks so much for your help. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Arg! Sorry `=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(Mortality!$C$21:$C$24,INDEX((COLUMN(A:A)-1)*4,1),0,4,1),'Rel‌​ative risks'!$B$6:$B$9)` Copied the INDEX Part form German Excel and corrected only SPALTE to COLUMN but not ; to ,

Comment: If the object is to fill down for additional offset values, that formula would also work as `=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(Mortality!$C$21:$C$24,INDEX((ROW(1:1)-1)*4, 1),0,4,1),'Relative risks'!$B$6:$B$9)`.

Comment: @ArielChairez - by helper row, I mean you can use an adjacent cell to hold the `COLUMN()` part of the formula, and then substitute the `COLUMN()` in the main formula with a reference to this cell. You would fill both cells across to get your desired output.